# How to find sum of each row of a dataframe having some missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have an dataframe , where I need to find the sum of each rows with missing values between them. 
what I have tried :

```
data['sumval'] = data.sum(axis=1, skipna = True)
```

But as a result the value I am getting in sumval column is 0.0

Comment: Could you share some example data? That would help understand the problem. Your code looks fine, but it may be something with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill the nan with 0, since it doesn't change the value of the sum:

```
data['sumval'] = data.fillna(0).sum(axis=1)
```